# Pass functional component to Animated.createAnimatedComponent

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

If you try to pass functional (non react class) component to `Animated.createAnimatedComponent` it throws an error that says

> Stateless functional components are invalid as children of createAnimatedComponent

Coming from an app that uses react hooks, basically all of my component are functional.

Is there a way / helper that can allow to pass these to `createAnimatedComponent` without wrapping them in `Animated.View` or even just `View`?

Here is an example of component that I want to make animatable

```js
function MyComponent({ someProp }) {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{counter}</Text>
    </View>
  );

}
```

Comment: What is `useState(0)` ?

Comment: @hongdevelop React Hooks.

Comment: @hongdevelop here is more info on hooks https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Comment: Only call Hooks from React function components. Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions. (There is just one other valid place to call Hooks — your own custom Hooks.

Comment: They say you have to make your own Hooks.

Comment: @hongdevelop What are you saying? `MyComponent` is a React component...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your options are:

1) Change to class component

2) Wrap your component in a `View` which you then animate

3) Use `react-native-animatable` (or a solution similar as this offers): check 
[here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-animatable#imperative-usage) for a combination of the library and refs

4) Maybe a solution similar to [this one](https://www.reactnativeschool.com/building-an-animation-hook-in-react-native) would suit you better. Combination of `useRef` and `useEffect`.

Comment: another way is you can use React.forwardRef

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22066#issuecomment-513274905

Answer (score 9):

How about this HOC

```
export function withAnimated(
  WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<any>,
): ComponentType {
  const displayName =
    WrappedComponent.displayName || WrappedComponent.name || 'Component';

  class WithAnimated extends React.Component {
    static displayName = `WithAnimated(${displayName})`;

    render(): React.ReactNode {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  }

  return Animated.createAnimatedComponent(WithAnimated);
}
```

#### Usage

`export const AnimatedGradientButton = withAnimated(GradientButton);`